# How to get the scrollHeight property of an document in IE using C#

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, dom, com-interop

I am using mshtml COM component in C# to get DOM element information in current Internet Explorer.
my code looks like this:

```
HTMLDocument document =....;
var offsetHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;// works fine
var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;//compiler error
```

The type HTMLDocument comes from the Microsoft.mshtml.dll COM component.
why the scrollHeight property of a DOM element, which can be accessed by javascript ,can't be accessed by C#? How can I get the scroll bar status of a running IE process by another .Net application?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference if someone is doing this same thing.
The offsetHeight is mentioned to be better in some cases since it accounts for borders but if you say, want to scroll the entirety of an IE page you would want to use the scroll height as said here.

To retrieve the scroll height you need to cast the body element to the IHTMLTextContainer interface which has got this property:

```
int pageHeight = ((IHTMLTextContainer)document.body).scrollHeight;
```

Hope this helps someone.